# Vue не отображается дата в поле <input>

Tags: html, vue.js

С сервера получаю объект `offer` с переменной `createdAt: "2023-03-27T16:13:21"`

В компоненте Vue соответственно пытаюсь отобразить ее следующим образом

```
<label>Дата создания.</label>
<input v-model="offer.createdAt"
       type="date"
       class="form-control mb-3" />
```

Но в итоге получаю это, т.е. существующая дата в поле ввода не отображается. (Остальные поля input отображаются корректно)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

UPD:

После получения объекта строка

```
this.offer.createdAt = new Date(this.offer.createdAt).toISOString().split('T')[0];
```

помогла исправить положение. Она это `2023-03-27T16:13:21` превратила в это `2023-03-27`. Почему-то поле `<input>` требует для отображения формат даты `yyyy-mm-dd`, но преобразовывать каждый раз вручную мне кажется слишком грубо. Может есть вариант избежать этого?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была решена довольно просто: изменила `type="date"` на `type="datetime"`

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете использоваться библиотеку Moment.js, которая предоставляет простой и гибкий API для управления и форматирования дат в JavaScript.

Вот пример того, как вы можете использовать Moment.js для форматирования значения даты в компоненте Vue:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <label>Дата создания.</label>
    <input v-model="formattedDate"
           type="date"
           class="form-control mb-3" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import moment from 'moment';

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      offer: {
        createdAt: "2023-03-27T16:13:21"
      }
    }
  },
  computed: {
    formattedDate() {
      return moment(this.offer.createdAt).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Интересный способ. К данной ситуации в целом тоже не сильно подходит, ведь хотелось совсем убрать дополнительное форматирование (например если будет много дат, то снова придется прописывать для каждого). Но в целом все равно спасибо, потому что это решение подойдет для другого проекта